# TOEFL grammar question

Tags: sentence-structure, adverbial-phrases

> When a left hand has been stenciled, this implies that the artist was right-handed, and vice versa. Even though the paint was often sprayed on by mouth, one can assume that the dominant hand assisted in the operation. One also has to make the assumption that **hands were stenciled palm downward**—a left hand stenciled palm upward might of course look as if it were a right hand.

Could you please explain the grammar of the bolded sentence? I know 'hands' is the subject and 'were stenciled' is the verb. What does do the rest ('palm downward') of the bolded sentence do?

Also, is this a complex sentence or compound sentence?

Reference: TOEFL

Comment: See also [this thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hands-were-stenciled-palm-downward%E2%80%94a-left-hand.3297308/) at Word Reference Language Forums.

Answer (score 1):

*One also has to make the assumption **that hands were stenciled palm downward***.

The bold part is not a stand-alone sentence; it is an adjectival clause qualifying *assumption*, the direct object of the verb *make*. In that clause, *hands* is the subject, *were stenciled* is the verb phrase and *palm downward* is the adverbial phrase. The sentence, *One also...palm downward*, is a complex sentence.

Comment: Could you recommend me some references like textbooks or website? 

I hope to study that kind of adverbial phrase 'palm downward'.

Comment: @lee: **1-** You can have almost all grammar terms in a simple and concise manner here:http://www.k12reader.com/term-category/grammar-terms/  **2-** There are a lot of example sentences with the adverbial phrase **palm down** here:http://www.k12reader.com/term-category/grammar-terms/. **3-**  Here you can see **palms downward** used as adverbials:https://books.google.co.in/books?id=I5CmWFOxOecC&pg=PA49&dq=%22palms+downward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN8P7M3o3WAhUEUbwKHfYpDX44ChDoAQhEMAU#v=onepage&q=%22palms%20downward%22&f=false

Comment: **4-** Here also you can see **palms downward** used as an adverb phrase: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=49REtr03IHgC&pg=PA29&dq=%22palms+downward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN8P7M3o3WAhUEUbwKHfYpDX44ChDoAQhKMAY#v=onepage&q=%22palms%20downward%22&f=false. Link for **2** above (https://glosbe.com/en/en/palm%20down)

Answer (score 0):

[Mahmud](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/141422/52137) may have been replying to an earlier edit but the currently bolded phrase

> **hands were stenciled palm downward**

is a [simple sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Simple_sentences). “Hands” is a plural noun subject; “were stenciled” is a plural [indicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realis_mood) [past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_tense#English) [passive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) verb; and “palm downward” is an [modificative adverbial adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)). It could be rephrased “with the palms facing downward,” “the palms having been pressed downward,” &c. “Hands were stenciled once the palms had been placed against the rock” would be a [complex sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Complex_and_compound-complex_sentences) but that’s not how it’s currently phrased.

The full sentence

> One also has to make the assumption that hands were stenciled palm downward—a left hand stenciled palm upward might of course look as if it were a right hand.

is a [compound-complex sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Complex_and_compound-complex_sentences) since it is an [independent clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause) (*One... has to make...*) with a [dependent clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause) (*...**that** hands were stenciled...*) and another [independent clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause) (*...a... hand... might... look...*) with another [dependent clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause) (*...**as if** it were...*). If the original question was just asking for the first half, then Mahmud was right that it is just [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Complex_and_compound-complex_sentences).